# Detecting Singularities in a Graph

Tags: java, algorithm, math, graphics, graph

I am creating a graphing calculator in Java as a project for my programming class. There are two main components to this calculator: the graph itself, which draws the line(s), and the equation evaluator, which takes in an equation as a `String` and... well, evaluates it.

To create the line, I create a `Path2D.Double` instance, and loop through the points on the line. To do this, I calculate as many points as the graph is wide (e.g. if the graph itself is 500px wide, I calculate 500 points), and then scale it to the window of the graph.

Now, this works perfectly for most any line. However, it does not when dealing with [singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_singularity).

If, when calculating points, the graph encounters a domain error (such as 1/0), the graph closes the shape in the `Path2D.Double` instance and starts a new line, so that the line looks mathematically correct. Example:

[image: Good Asymptote]
<sub>(source: [imagesocket.com](http://content.imagesocket.com/images/good_line7cd.png))</sub>

However, because of the way it scales, sometimes it is rendered correctly, sometimes it isn't. When it isn't, the actual asymptotic line is shown, because within those 500 points, it skipped over `x = 2.0` in the equation `1 / (x-2)`, and only did `x = 1.98` and `x = 2.04`, which are perfectly valid in that equation. Example:

[image: Bag Asymptote]
<sub>(source: [imagesocket.com](http://content.imagesocket.com/images/bad_linef6e.png))</sub>

In that case, I increased the window on the left and right one unit each.

My question is: **Is there a way to deal with singularities using this method of scaling so that the resulting line looks mathematically correct?**

I myself have thought of implementing a binary search-esque method, where, if it finds that it calculates one point, and then the next point is wildly far away from the last point, it searches in between those points for a domain error. I had trouble figuring out how to make it work in practice, however.

Thank you for any help you may give!

Comment: Why not try to derive your function to find out if there are asymptotes and where they are?

Comment: I imagine doing this the right way is pretty difficult, but I don't know for sure. One way to avoid this is to decrease your step size (say at most 0.01, preferably 0.001 or even less, so definitely calculate more than 500 points) and not draw lines at all. If the points themselves are close enough, the rendering will look just fine for most functions. However, it might not for exponential functions and in general functions that grow really fast. It's also going to be slower. Just an idea until and if I think of something better. I'm also not sure if this is doable in Java, but it should.

Comment: @IVlad That method of calculation was how I did it before I created my current system. The reason I moved away from static steps is because of the speed. It got to the point where it would be calculating thousands of points for a 500px graph if the window was 40 units across, and there would be a noticeable lag. I also tried your only-plot-points idea before I asked this question, but it ended looking weird for exponential functions, so I dropped the idea.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention that the graph is 40 units across. The distance should be calculated in terms of pixels, not the domain of the function you are graphing. Also, if plotting points, you should have the number of points depend on the current slope of the function. Horizontal lines should take one point per pixel while nearly vertical lines will take more.

Comment: nasufara, you may want to edit this post, and replace asymptotes with singularities, since that is what you are really asking. The function y = 1 - exp(-x) has an asymptote as x->+\infty, and y->1, but you won't have any problem graphing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to have singularities graphed properly.

Essentially what I do is for every point on the graph, I check to see if it is inside the visible graphing clip. If I hit a point on the graph that is outside the visible clip, I graph that first point outside the clip, and then stop graphing any invisible points after that.

I keep calculating points and checking if they are inside the visible clip, not graphing ones that are outside the clip. Once I hit a point that is inside the clip again, I graph the point *before* that point, and then graph the current point.

I keep doing this until I've graphed the entire line. This creates the illusion that the entire line is begin drawn, when only the visible parts are.

This won't work if the window is large and the actual graph size in pixels is small, but it does suffice for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use interval arithmetic ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic ) and calculate the interval of the function on each interval [x(i), x(i+1)]. If the resulting interval is infinite, skip that line segment. Speed-wise this should only be a couple times slower than just evaluating the function.

Comment: Could you please provide more info on this? How would one calculate the interval for each interval, and how would this help? Does it work for a function that has both left and right limit equal in the singularity point?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mostly on the right track.

1. I don't think figure 2 is mathematically incorrect.
2. For bonus points, you should have a routine which checks the diff between two consecutive values y1 & y2, and if it is greater than a threshold, inserts more points between y1 and y2, until no diff is greater than the threshold. If this iterative rountine is unable to get out of the while loop after 10 iterations or so, then that indicates presence of a singularity, and you can remove the plot between y1 and y2. That will give you figure 1.

Comment: This is pretty easy to fool though. Consider the function 0.1/abs(x-1). All consecutive points are very close together (and can be made even closer by using 0.01 for example), so thresholds won't always work. I think we can also find functions where you would actually check the wrong consecutive points and not the right ones, maybe by using exponential functions. Consider (e^x - 1)/abs(x)

Comment: @IVlad I don't understand your problem. I think that morpheus offers a pretty good subroutine ('intervalnesting') which is also easy to implement. the only minor enhancement I would do is to define the y-threshold-value from the previous interval ...

Comment: I think what are referring to is the case when there is a singularity between y1 & y2, but |y1-y2| is less than threshold. That is certainly possible.

Comment: I meant what @morpheus explained. My functions are examples in which there is a singularity between y1 & y2, but |y1 - y2| might not even enter the threshold, and if it does, chances are all the other intervals will too, so it's going to be pretty slow, depending on how many times we make it iterate each interval. It's a good idea, just that it won't always work.

Answer (score 1):

If morpehus's solution is too slow for you, you can consider all the absolute values of jumps between two consecutive function values, and try to identifies large [outliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) -- these will be the infinite jumps.

If you decide to try this, and need help, leave a comment here.

Comment: I'd sure like some help doing this! :)